# What is the name of the wrinkles occurring in people's lips?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

I was wondering if there is a name for the wrinkles occurring in people's lips.
Just curious.

Comment: What research of your own have you tried performing to answer this question? We ask that all question askers perform their own research before posting . Thanks.